# I want to get all MP3 files from the Android storage device in my audio player app in Flutter and show them in the Listview.Builder

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am making a *music* player app in Flutter and want to show a list of all songs fetched from the internal storage of device, but I can't see to find the correct code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class Songlist extends StatefulWidget {

    @override
    _SonglistState createState() => _SonglistState();
}

class _SonglistState extends State<Songlist> {
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        initlist();
    }

    void initlist() async {
        if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
            Directory dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
            List<FileSystemEntity> files;
            files = dir.listSync(recursive: true, followLinks: false);
        }
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("Your Media"),
                backgroundColor: mycolor,
            ),
            /* body: new ListView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                itemCount: files.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return buildRow(_files.elementAt(i).path);
                }),
            */
            );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [flute_music_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flute_music_player) package to get the songs.

First add these two permissions to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then get the songs:

```
List<Song> songs = [];

Future<void> getSongs() async {
  songs = await MusicFinder.allSongs();
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getSongs();
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: songs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var song = songs[index];

          return ListTile(
            title: Text(song.title),
            subtitle: Row(
              children: [
                Text(song.artist),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried flute_music_player but it has issues and showing plugin incompatibility errors